# Facebook audience network Ads(rewarded, banner, interstitial ad) not showing up in release mode

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-ads-api, facebook-audience-network, facebook-ads

I have an app which is supposed to show some ads using Facebook audience network in debug mode. But in release mode, nothing happens, even though the exact same code is running debug version. In release mode(**Download it from Google playstore**) it shows an error in logcat like this for

**Error:**
**Interstitial - 'Interstitial ad failed to load: The display format in the ad request does not match the display format specified for this placement. Each placement can only be used with a single display format. You can create multiple placements in order to use multiple display formats.**',

for **Rewarded Video error in logcat shows like this-'Rewarded video ad failed to load: No fill.**'

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe your problem due to sdk version. Check you this problem( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64962584/fb-ads-not-loaded-when-i-update-fan-to-6-2-0-but-ad-loaded-shown-on-5-sdk-wi ) and switch back your fb sdk version then check.

Answer (score 2):

Newly created Ad Units take some time to be served. If your app is showing ads in debug mode, then everything is fine on your side.

Comment: Thanks for the reply bro. But I've created the application and integrated sdk in my project 1 week before .

Comment: Are you using one ad Id for all your ads? or mixing ad units?

Comment: No I'm using separate placement id's for each ad formats.

Comment: interstitial_fb = new com.facebook.ads.InterstitialAd(this, getString(R.string.fb_interestial_placement_id));
        //interstitial_fb.setAdListener(new loadAdafterShowing());
         com.facebook.ads.InterstitialAd.InterstitialLoadAdConfig loadIntersAdConfig = interstitial_fb.buildLoadAdConfig()
        .withAdListener(new loadAdafterShowing())
        .build();
        interstitial_fb.loadAd(loadIntersAdConfig);

Comment: this is how i am loading with audience network 6.1.0. and it works perfectly fine

Comment: Same way i did it in my  source code,interstitialAd_fb = new InterstitialAd(this, "**********");
interstitialAd_fb.loadAd(interstitialAd_fb.buildLoadAdConfig()
                        .withAdListener(interstitialAdListener)
                        .build());

Comment: as i said the problem is not on your side. some of the time they don,t have any Add to fill

Comment: are you calling to  interstitial_fb.loadAd(loadIntersAdConfig);?? i dont see that line in your code